# how to draw two lines in a graph matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my python code for `Matplotlib`, I want to draw two lines, the first one it's succeed already, I want to add one more line into this graph, which is y=x^(-0.56), so I just simply add one (x,y) pair after it, the code returns an error:

```
lines = plt.loglog(x, y,basex=10,'ro',x,x**(-0.56),basex=10)


SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Can anyone help how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats because you are using first basex=10 as a default argument and after that you are passing non-default arguments. If you are sure that your function needs these 7 arguments, then remove the first basex=10.

You can also see the error if you format your code like this:

```
>>> lines = matplotlib.loglog(x,<br>
... y,<br>
... basex=10,<br>
... 'ro',<br>
... x,<br>
... x**(-0.56),<br>
... 10<br>
... )<br>
  File "<stdin>", line 4<br>
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

The error clearly shows some problem with line 4 and the reason is that I specified above.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first `basex=10` from your argument list (this is your keyword arg and it is complaining you have non-keyword args after it).

i.e.

```
lines = plt.loglog(x, y,'ro',x,x**(-0.56),basex=10)
```

To make it more explicit you could also write it as:

```
line1 = plt.loglog(x, y,'ro',basex=10)
line2 = plt.loglog(x,x**(-0.56),basex=10)
plt.show()
```